# How to force a pseudo-state in a widget

Tags: qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

I have my custom widget where I defined my stylesheet like this:

```
QWidget#this { background-color: red; }
QWidget#this:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

This works when I move the mouse over the widget but I don't have this behaviour when I'm dragging another widget over the first one.

I have captured the `DragMove` event but can't figure out to send something like `mouseHover` event (`MouseMove` events doesn't seem to work).

Is this possible?  Is there another way to use the stylesheet when I'm dragging another widget?

Comment: Did you try `QWidget::dragEnterEvent()`?

Comment: Well, I have this behaviour implemented in Stylesheets so I wanted to solve it using the same method. With dragEnterEvent I can capture the event but can't change the stylesheet to the specified for the hover pseudo state

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem a few days ago. Try to define a custom property for your widget, something like *dragging*, and use conditionals for your style sheet:

```
QWidget#this[dragging=true]{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Maybe you will need to use [QStyle::polish()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#polish) after changing the custom property, in order to refresh your widget style.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But this doesn't solve my problem because I will have to set that property (and unset it) by hand when I receive dragEnter and dragLeave events. The beauty of the hover pseudo event is that it is called automatically and that's why I wanted to use it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Calling in the paintEvent for stylable widgets (the 4 lines of code that come in the documentation for QWidget in stylesheet ref.) at the end a style()->polish(this) method, worked for me!